# Identify this set: assemblies of black plates and tiles

Tags: set-identification

I have these parts but not what set they are to.
Can you help me with what set they are a part of?
What set is this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Based on [6171264: TILE 4X4, W/ BOW](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6171264) in black, this is from:

[75296: Darth Vader Meditation Chamber](https://brickset.com/sets/75296-1/Darth-Vader-Meditation-Chamber)

[image]